# Todo list tutorial on parse doesn't let me view the app

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to see what the Javascript Todo tutorial does and when the page loads I fill the signup fields and press sign up I get the following message: "To view this page, you must log in to area “Parse” on api.parse.com:443." and it asks for a name and password and even though I tried my parse account it won't log me in. can anyone help me?

http://parseplatform.github.com/Todo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the app is non-functional because the `js\todos.js` file it is referencing has the following lines:

```
// Initialize Parse with your Parse application javascript keys
Parse.initialize("your-application-id",
                 "your-javascript-key");
```

You need to download the files and host them on either a local dev server or equivalent and replace those placeholders with actual values before it will work.